# Table loading based on form submission on same page, Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a page with a table that loads information based on variables in my controller. I am now trying to implement a form on the page. I want the form to initiate the table information instead of the controller. I have to take the form information and do some logic against the database to filter the information on the table. Something like this:

```
<% @tableResellers = [] %>
<% if @tableResellers << @reseller.company_region.include?(reseller.company_region) %>
<td><% @tableResellers.company_region %></td>
```

How do you get the form information into @tableResellers on the same page and instantly load the table information?

My Form:

```
<%= form_for(@reseller) do |f| %>
<fieldset>      
    <div class="row">
        <span class="span5 pagination-right">
            Region <span style="color: red">*</span>
            <%= f.select :company_region, options_for_select([ ["North America", "North America"], ...]) %>
        </span>
        <span class="span6"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="span5 pagination-right">
            Country <span style="color: red">*</span>
            <%= f.select :company_country, options_for_select([ ['Australia', 'Australia'], ... ]) %>
        </span>
        <span class="span6"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <span class="span5 pagination-right">
            State/Province <span style="color: red">*</span>
            <%= f.select :company_state, options_for_select([ ['Alabama', 'Alabama'], ...]) %>
        </span>
        <span class="span6"></span>
    </div>
        <div class="row">
        <span class="span5 pagination-right">
            City <span style="color: red">*</span>
            <%= f.text_field :company_city, placeholder: "City" %>
        </span>
    </div>

</fieldset>
<hr />
<p class="pagination-centered">
    <%= f.submit "Register", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

My Table Body:

```
<tbody>
    <% @resellers.each do |reseller| %>
        <tr>
                <td><%= reseller.contact_name %></td>
                <td><%= link_to reseller.company_name, grandstreamers_reseller_path(reseller) %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.company_region %></td>

                <% if reseller.company_country == "United States" %>
                <td><%= reseller.company_state %></td>
                <% else %>
                <td><%= reseller.company_country %></td>
                <% end %>
                <td><%= reseller.company_city %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.area_served.gsub(/['-]/, '')%></td>                    
                <td><%= reseller.contact_email %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.company_website %></td>
                <td><%= reseller.approved ? "Yes" : "No" %></td>
            <% if @reseller_users_incerts.include?(reseller.id) %>
                <td><%= "Yes" %></td>
            <% else %>
                <td><%= "No" %></td>
            <% end %>
                <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_grandstreamers_reseller_path(reseller) %>
            </tr>

    <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You mean you want to post the form and add a new row to the table, based on the data posted by the form?

Comment: The form gets filled in by the client in their browser, so you'd be talking say ajax to do something like that. PS Way too much logic for a view and a bit of css would help.

Comment: The form is to filter out results on the table. I am not trying to edit the actual information. Just what is displayed based on what is submitted. So if they enter United States I want to use display Resellers in the United States. The main thing here is I want to have country, city and state as options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, you are looking to a partial to draw the table, let's call it:

```
_draw_resellers.html.erb
```

So, what I would do would be to post the form data with an ajax method to an action in the controller that will render the PARTIAL (not the view, because it will reload your full asset library).

In your controller you would probably do something like this:

```
def resellers_table
    @resellers=Reseller.where(your_params).all
    render :partial 'draw_resellers'
end
```

You could use the basic jquery ajax function for that. You need, of course, to add an id to your table or tbody (tab_resellers, for instance) in order to replace the html with the ajax response text. So, you should replace your f.submit with a button to call your ajax function.

Check here for the method. 
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
It's quite straightforward. Basically, your button would be something like

```
<%= link_to_function "Register", "draw_my_table(your_params)" %>
```

and your js

```
function draw_my_table(your_params)  
{ 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        url: your_url,  //the route to your url with the params (if form is 'get' method)
        beforeSend: function(data)
        {
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            $('#tab_resellers').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

**Edit:**

Your main view would be something like this:

controller:

```
def filter_resellers #for example
    @resellers=Reseller.all
    @reseller= #not sure what it is, could be plain html form, not rails form
end
```

and your view, filter_resellers.html.erb

```
<table>
    <tr>
    #headers
    </tr>
    <tdata id='tab_resellers'>
        <%= render :partial => 'draw_resellers' %>
    </tdata>
</table>

<% form_for ....
```

Your partial, `_draw_resellers.html.erb`, would be, as you write it

```
<% @resellers.each do |reseller| %>
...
<% end %>
```

Comment: Where would the form come in or the filtering?